# Need to put one custom hashmap into another hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have below maps:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Employee>> hmap = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Employee>>();

HashMap<Integer, Employee> emap = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

I am using keyset to get the object out of emap and compare the employee salary.
If the salary is less than particular amount I need to put that map into hmap with key as 0 and if it is more then with key as 1.

```
for(Integer e: emap.keySet())
    {
        if(emap.get(e).getSalary()<45000.0)
        {
            hmap.put(0,//what should i put here );
        }
        else
        {
            hmap.put(1,//what should i put here );
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why should `hmap` not be `HashMap<Integer, Employee>` too? And what if you have more than 2 maps, what will you do as you only have `0` and `1` as key?

Comment: The hmap will only have 2 keys, 1 and 0. 1 for all valid records of emap and 0 for all invalid.

Comment: You needs to declare it as Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Employee>> instead of HashMap. Use interface type if possible.

Comment: Just use `partitionBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two auxiliaries map:

```
Map<Integer, Employee> lowSalaryEmployees = new HashMap<>();  
Map<Integer, Employee> highSalaryEmployees = new HashMap<>();
```

Then fill them in the for loop and put them in your `hmap`:

```
for (Integer k: emap.keySet()) {
    Employee e = emap.get(k);
    if (e.getSalary() < 45000.0) {
        lowSalaryEmployees.put(k, e);
    } else {
        highSalaryEmployees.put(k, e);
    }
}

hmap.put(0, lowSalaryEmployees);
hmap.put(1, highSalaryEmployees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared parameterised type of `hmap` as `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Employee>>`, then you could only out `HashMap<Integer,Employee>` type as value into `hmap`.